# SSL 2.0 Finished Message

Tags: public-key, tls

Reference to SSL 2.0 specs. from: [Mozilla - SSL 2.0](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ssl/draft02.html)
Can I conclude that SSL 2.0 Finish messages does not provide AMC for all the messages sent/received by both parties (as in TLS 1.2)? Due to lack of SSL 2.0 official detailed documentation, I am unable to confirm this.

```
2.2.1 Assuming no session-identifier

client-hello         C -> S: challenge, cipher_specs
server-hello         S -> C: connection-id,server_certificate,cipher_specs
client-master-key    C -> S: {master_key}server_public_key
client-finish        C -> S: {connection-id}client_write_key
server-verify        S -> C: {challenge}server_write_key
server-finish        S -> C: {new_session_id}server_write_key
```

Comment: Wait, the link actually says 0.2. That was never even released. What are you doing?

Comment: @Elias Title aside, that is the correct documentation for SSLv2.

Comment: @Xander You mean typing mistake in the title? How did you know that?

Comment: What do you mean by "AMC"?

Comment: @user2192774 It isn't a typing mistake. It's an artifact of a change in how version numbers are interpreted between the SSL2 and SSL3 specs.   SSL2 reads the version as "2" and SSL3 reads it as "0.2" so the version numbers (0.2 and v2)  are to some degree considered interchangable.

Comment: But you just wrote: `SSL3 reads it as "0.2"` then you said: `so the version numbers (0.2 and v2)`. How come SSL3 reads as 0.2 and also SSL2 reads as 0.2? Can you clarify please?

Comment: @user2192774 Because the version was defined to be a single int value, so the version `0x0002` is "2" in SSL2.  In v3, it was split into one byte for the major version and one byte for the minor version so the same value `0x0002` is read as "0.2" in SSL3.

Comment: @Xander Thanks. So the bottom line: the specs are for SSL v2.

Comment: @user2192774 Correct.  That is the SSL v2 specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SSL2 did not MAC the handshake. See (recentish and more available) [rfc6176](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6176)

> 2. SSL 2.0 Deficiencies

> SSL version 2.0 [SSL2] deficiencies include the following:

> ...

> o  Handshake messages are not protected.  This permits a man-in-the-
> middle to trick the client into picking a weaker cipher suite than
> it would normally choose.